# Detecting a type of a class

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is it possible to detect if a class is of certain type?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but for what?

Comment: What do you mean by the type of a class? A class is a type.

Comment: -1: As it stands, this question makes no sense.  Please clarify!

Comment: @sepp2k I guess it means if A is a subclass of B. All OP's 3 questions today are very vague (1-line) questions on C++ meta-programming. He should give more detail.

Comment: @sepp2k by type of a class I mean that one class can be of type MyClass and another class my be of type YourClass. Hope that's clarified

Comment: @There: So `A` could be `MyClass` and `B` could be `YourClass`, and you want to know if `A` and `B` are the same?

Comment: @There: Then what is wrong with GMan's answer below?

Comment: @There: Not at all. What does it mean if a class is of type MyClass? That it is a subclass of MyClass? That it *is* MyClass? That it is an instance of MyClass? The latter is impossible in C++ since classes can't be instances of classes.

Comment: @GMAN yep. That's what I'm trying to get from you guys

Comment: @There ...? So then how does my answer not work for you? `is_same<A, B>::value`?

Comment: @GMan I'm sorry I think I see how it can work. Deep appologggieees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value = false;
};


template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

is_same<int, float>::value; // false
is_same<int, int>::value; // true
```

These are called type traits, and you can find a slew of them in [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) and C++0x.

Comment: yo my man! this is detecting if types are the same not that they are of a certain type.

Comment: @There: Then your question makes no sense. If you want to know if "they are of a certain type", how is that different than checking "detecting if types are the same"? [As usual](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), ask about the big picture and problem you're trying to solve, not the tiny theoretical step you think you need to take.